# Python 2.7 argparse: How to take file_name and a file using single flag

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I need to take **file_name** and **ssh_key_file** using one single flag from user. Any help appreciated.
User input should look like this:
`python xx.py --file ssh_key_file.pub file_name`

**I have to use mutually exclusive group for some reason**

Sample code may look like below:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()`
xap = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group()`
xap.add_argument('--file', 
                 dest='exp_kp',
                 nargs=2,
                 type=argparse.FileType('rb'),
                 help='Key file and key name')`
```

Is it possible to take file_name in the above `--file` as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

Do you have other arguments to put in this group.  It's not useful with only one (even if it has nargs=2)

```
xap = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
```

As written this will treat both arguments as filenames and try to open both.  `type` applies to both arguments, not just one.

```
xap.add_argument('--file', 
                  dest='exp_kp',
                  nargs=2,
                  type=argparse.FileType('rb'),
                  help='Key file and key name')
```

`FileType` is just a convenience `type`.  It tries to open the file, and raises an argparse error if there are problems (and quits).  The disadvantage is that closing the opened file is now your responsibility.  You can't use it in a preferred `with` context.  It's only real advantage is that argparse error.

```
xap.add_argument('--file', 
                  dest='exp_kp',
                  nargs=2,
                  metavar=('FILE','KEY'),
                  help='Key file and key name')
```

This form will accept two strings, which you can then process as you want, e.g.

```
 with open(args.exp_kp[0],'rb') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
      for l in lines: 
          if args.exp_kp[1] in l:
              print(l)
```

If there problems opening this file you can still raise an argparse error with a `parser.error('put your message here') call.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I do have several other arguments both in `ap and xap`.
I've got your explanation/arguments. I wanted argparse to handle file IO, but could be fixed in your mentioned way.